# What is the polylineOptions parameters of the new Google Maps website?

Tags: google-maps, google-polyline, google-directions-api

I developed a website using Google Maps direction. My Polyline configuration is as following:

```
var lineSymbol = {
    path: 'M 1.5 1 L 1 0 L 1 2 M 0.5 1 L 1 0',
    fillColor: 'black',
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWeight: 2,
    strokeOpacity: 1
};

var pl = new google.maps.Polyline({
    strokeColor: '#426289',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 5,
    icons: [{
            icon: lineSymbol,
            offset: '25px',
            repeat: '100px'
        }]
});
```

With this parameters, my Polyline looks like below image

[image: My Maps Direction Polyline]

I wonder what is the Google Maps new website Polyline parameters (it looks embossed) ?

[image: Google Maps Direction Polyline]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any options on PolyLineOptions to create that 3d effect. You may consider draw 2 polylines, one thick (e.g. 5px width) and thiner one (3px) on top. Or render with TileOverlay https://github.com/dan-silver/Android-Street-View/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/TileProviderAndProjectionDemo.java.